# Django logout_then_login with next param

Tags: python, django

In some cases I want to logout user, redirect it to the login page with `next` param, so when user will succesfully logged in, Django should redirect user to the some page.

I've found `logout_then_login()` method but looks like it does not support next after login page param. I've tried to pass 'next' param in extra_content param, but it doesn't work.

How can I do this? Maybe there are some other django methods to do this?
Speaking generally, I just want to make forced logout, make user to re-login and redirect it to the page where it was logget out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) (Scroll down for this method)

**logout_then_login(request[, login_url, current_app, extra_context])**

Logs a user out, then redirects to the login page.

**URL name:** No default URL provided

**Optional arguments:**

- **login_url:** The URL of the login page to redirect to. Defaults to settings.LOGIN_URL if not supplied.
- **current_app:** A hint indicating which application contains the current view. See the namespaced URL resolution strategy for more information.
- **extra_context:** A dictionary of context data that will be added to the default context data passed to the template.

[Here we can see that the login method will accept a next parameter as a get variable.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required)

Adding next to the login_url should do what you want:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
def myView(request):
    login_url = "%s?next=%s" % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path)
    logout_then_login(request, login_url=login_url)
```